# mongodb find the document by id and then group the result based on name field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a collection with multiple documents like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a64d076bfd103df081967ae"),
    "status" : "",
    "Number" : 53,
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2015-05-18",
            "value" : 12.41
        },
        {
            "date" : "2015-05-19",
            "value" : 12.45
        },

    ],
    "Name" : "ABC Banking",
    "scheme":"ABC1",
    "createdDate" : "21-01-2018"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a64d076bfd103df081967ae"),
    "status" : "",
    "Number" : 53,
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2015-05-18",
            "value" : 13.41
        },
        {
            "date" : "2015-05-19",
            "value" : 13.45
        },

    ],
    "Name" : "ABC Banking",
    "scheme":"ABC2",
    "createdDate" : "21-01-2018"
}
```

I am Querying collection based on Number field like

```
db.getCollection('mfhistories').find({'Number':53})
```

to get all the documents with this Number.

Now I want to group all the collection with Name 'ABC Banking' into an array. so that I will get result based on Name.

so the result should be like

```
{        
   "Name":"ABC Banking",
   [
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a64d076bfd103df081967ae"),
        "status" : "",
        "Number" : 53,
        "values" : [ 
            {
                "date" : "2015-05-18",
                "value" : 13.41
            },
           {
               "date" : "2015-05-19",
               "value" : 13.45
           }, 
        ],
            "scheme":"ABC1",
            "createdDate" : "21-01-2018"
       },
       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a64d076bfd103df081967ae"),
            "status" : "",
            "Number" : 53,
            "values" : [ 
            {
               "date" : "2015-05-18",
               "value" : 13.41
            },
            {
               "date" : "2015-05-19",
               "value" : 13.45
            }
           ], 
          "scheme":"ABC2",
           "createdDate" : "21-01-2018"
         }
    ]
}
```

Please help..

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework for that:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { Number: 53, Name: "ABC Banking" }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Name",
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Name: "$_id",
            _id: 0,
            docs: 1
        }
    }
])
```

`$$ROOT` is a special variable which captures entire document. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mfhistories.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                Number: 53
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    Name: '$Name'
                },
                docObj: {
                    $addToSet: '$$CURRENT'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                Name: '$_id.Name',
                docObj: 1,
                _id: 0
            }
        }

    ]


);
```